# iPhone - Changing app settings while application is running in the background

Tags: iphone, ios, nsuserdefaults, multitasking

The problem i am having is if i make changes to the application settings while the application is running in the background the changes aren't available in my app until it is restarted. Am i missing something or is this way it is?

Thanks very much. Sj

Comment: Do you mean that the app isn't reloading the settings, or that when it reloads them it still sees the old settings?

Comment: Hi there, That's what I meant I just realised I needed to call synchronise on the NSUserDefault object on one of the delegate functions listed below. Cheers Sj

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use

```
-(void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
```

or

```
 -(void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

in your App delegate to reconfigure your app. The first is sent when your app resumes after being in the background. The second is sent both on resume **and** after the first time launch.

See the chart in [this article](http://www.drobnik.com/touch/2010/07/understanding-ios-4-backgrounding-and-delegate-messaging/) for details.

Comment: Cheers - Calling [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize] in one of those did the trick! Sj